# Guice @Provides function with optional Nullable injection not works

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, guice

Code first:

```
@Slf4j
public class HelperModule extends AbstractModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {

    }

    @Provides
    @Named("plugin")
    @Singleton
    public Reflections getReflections(@Nullable @Named("plugin-scope") String pluginScope)
    {
        if (pluginScope == null)
        {
            pluginScope = "me.wener";
        }
        log.info("Create plugin scanner for '{}'", pluginScope);
        return new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(pluginScope))
                .addScanners(
                        new SubTypesScanner(),
                        new TypeAnnotationsScanner())
//                .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(".*\\.java").exclude(".*"))
        );
    }
}
```

What I expected is `pluginScope` can be null and optional, I follow the instruction [Use @Nullable](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable), but this is not works, I still got

```
No implementation for java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=plugin-scope) was bound
```

What's wrong ?

**EDIT**
BTW,The `@Nullable` is `javax.annotation.Nullable`

Comment: What about `@Inject(optional=true)` ?

Comment: @MilanBaran tried,still not wrks

Answer (score 4):

A `@Nullable` annotation means that you can bind to a Provider that returns `null`, *not that the binding can be absent*. Your @Nullable annotation is what would allow the following to work:

```
bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("plugin-scope"))
    .toProvider(Providers.<String>of(null));
```

You explicitly must bind to a Provider of `null`, rather than `toInstance(null)`, according to an [internal Guice error message](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/AbstractBindingBuilder.java#L41).